# Decoding a coded variable

Tags: vb.net, security, encoding, decoding

I use this function in order to encode an input:

```
Public Function encodeStrings(ByVal MyPass As String, ByVal MyUName As String) As String
    Dim ENPass As String = Nothing
    Dim password As String = (MyPass + MyUName)
    Dim mhash As HashAlgorithm = New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim bytValue() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)
    Dim bytHash() As Byte = mhash.ComputeHash(bytValue)
    mhash.Clear()
    ENPass = Convert.ToBase64String(bytHash)
    Return ENPass
End Function
```

Now I need to decode this variable and get back the original string.

Does anyone know how to do that? I'm using VB.NET in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to decode it.  The `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` implements a [hashing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).  According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1cryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Computes the SHA1 hash value for the input data...

SHA-1 is, by definition a hashing algorithm.  According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1):

> In cryptography, SHA-1 is a cryptographic hash function designed by the United States National Security Agency and published by the United States NIST as a U.S. Federal Information Processing Standard.  SHA-1 produces a 160-bit (20-byte) hash value. A SHA-1 hash value is typically expressed as a hexadecimal number, 40 digits long.

That is why it inherits from the [`HashAlgorithm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) base-class rather than the [`SymmetricAlgorithm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) base-class.  Since it uses a hashing algorithm, that means that it is one-way encoded.  The original string will always result in the same encrypted value, but there is no way to decrypt it to get back to the original value, since many different strings could result in that same encrypted value (although, with [cryptographic hashing algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), such as SHA1, that is unfeasible).

If you think about it, that's the only thing that makes sense.  If the SHA-1 algorithm always results in a hash code which is 20 bytes long, then that means you could encode a 1 gigabyte string and it would still only be 20 bytes long as an SHA-1 encrypted hash value.  Surely you don't think that those 20 bytes contain *all* of the data that was originally stored in that 1 GB string.  If that were the case, zipping files would be *far* more effective :)

Typically, when a cryptographic hashing algorithm is being used, it would be for something like storing a password.  In that case, the issue is not how to decrypt the password, but rather, to encrypt the newly entered password and then compare the two encrypted values to see if they are the same.  If the two encrypted values are the same, then you know that the user entered the right password.  If the two encrypted values are not the same, then you know that it is incorrect (but you still don't know what the right password would be).

If you need a 2-way encryption algorithm, you need to use one which inherits from `SymmetricAlgorithm`, such as the [`AesCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: Well I having this feeling but it is better to hear from one else as a confirmation. Thank you very much, for your help.